# Toggler Icon disappears when making bootstrap navbar transparent

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav id="fondo" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);">

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

</nav>

<div style="height:1000px"></div>
```

I have made a transparent navbar with bootstrap but when the toggler-icon has to appear it is there but it is transparent too and I can't figure out how to make it visible.

I don't know what part of the code you need to see to see where my error is, but I leave my local server open so you can see the html and css codes.

http://87.218.3.238/cbd/

Comment: Add your relevant code from the navbar and toggler-icon. It looks like you need to specify the type of background it is being used on. Add ```navbar-dark``` class to your ```nav#fondo``` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one of the required classes to the `#fondo` navigation, so the `svg` from bootstrap can be loaded correctly.

In your case, most likely:

```
<nav id="fondo" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav id="fondo" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);">

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

</nav>

<div style="height:1000px"></div>
```

Comment: I already have the style in the css file:  #fondo {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: 0.5s;
}

Comment: Based on those classes bootstrap loads the svg image for the toggler-icon.

Comment: You just made my day. Thanks for this. It's so easy, yet hidden in the tutorials on BS

Answer (score 0):

with jquery

```
var cdbMenu = $("#fondo");
var cdbMenuSize = 992;
function cdbMenuSwap()
{
    if (window.innerWidth >= cdbMenuSize) {
        cdbMenu.css({"background-color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)"});
    } else {
        cdbMenu.removeAttr('style');
    }
}
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    cdbMenuSwap();
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    cdbMenuSwap();
});
```